# PySpark: How to remove duplicates from a RDD by first occurance?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

How to remove duplicates of a key in the RDD and keep its least occurrence (part of key) for a key?

Example for comparison value in key:

`RDD = [('2A',1),('2B',2),('2A',3),('1A',3),('1B',16)]`

Output: `[('1A',3),('2A',1),('2A',3)]`

Compare the `key[2:]` and keep all occurrences of least value.

In example for all keys starting with '2' One is minimum among(2One and 2Two), so I need to keep all the values of key containing 2One.

Comment: You're going to need a precedence table of some sort to be able to compare 'One' and 'Two' and programmatically return which one is bigger.

Comment: I will update example to simply use A and B

Comment: Updated my answer to incorporate something reasonably close to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit: the following answer was written to answer OP's original question, which was about how to remove duplicates by key and keep only those with minimum value.*

```
sc.parallelize([(2,3),(2,1),(1,3),(1,0)]).
groupByKey().
map(lambda (x,y): (x,min(y))).
collect()
```

All you need is to first group by key, and then map each tuple to the minimum in its value.

When you group by key, you get something of the sort:

```
[(1, [3,0]), (2, [3,1])]
```

From there, it is a simple matter to use `min` and `map` to keep only the tuples you want.

---

To answer the new question,

```
sc.parallelize([('2A',1),('2B',2),('2A',3),('1A',3),('1B',16)]).
groupByKey(). # groups together everything
groupBy(lambda (x,y): x[0]). #groups by digit 2, 1, etc. in key name
map(lambda (x,y): min(y)). # chooses smallest of 2A, 2B, etc.
map(lambda (x,y): (x,list(y))).collect()
```

yields `[('1A', [3]), ('2A', [1, 3])]`, which is close enough.

Comment: Thanks for response, but that was not I intented to ask. I have edited my example. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `groupByKey` for large datasets. Use `reduceByKey`

```
sc.parallelize([('2A',1),('2B',2),('2A',3),('1A',3),('1B',16)])\
  .reduceByKey(min)\
  .collect()
```

Answer (score -2):

```
RDD = [(2,3),(2,1),(1,3),(1,0)] 
temp = {}
for item in RDD:
    if item[0] not in temp.keys():
        temp[item[0]] = []
    temp[item[0]].append(item[1])

new_RDD = [(item[0], sorted(item[1])[0]) for item in temp.iteritems()]
print new_RDD
```

Comment: This doesn't make use of PySpark at all.